# CentOS 7 httpd /server-status limitations

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, munin, centos7, virtualhost

I have got VPS (using CentOS 7 as my OS) and now I am configuring **Munin** (monitoring software). I ran into a little problem with Apache monitoring.

Now I have got this cfg in my **httpd.conf** and everything works fine:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
</Location>
```

Terminal munin:

```
munin-node-configure --suggest | grep apache
apache_accesses            | yes  | yes                                    
apache_processes           | yes  | yes                                    
apache_volume              | yes  | yes
```

But with this settings is `/server-status` available via all domain in the server:

```
example.com/server-status
example.net/server-status
192.0.2.1/example-status
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
example.com/server-status  ---> ERROR 404
example.net/server-status ---> ERROR 404
192.0.2.1/example-status     ---> OK
```

So when I move the cfg from httpd.conf to my **vhost default file**, which now looks:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/server
    ErrorLog /var/log/www/server_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/www/server_requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And after update:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/server
    ErrorLog /var/log/www/server_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/www/server_requests.log combined

<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Munin then stop monitor the apache service and will say:

```
apache_accesses            | yes  | no [apache server-status not found. check if mod_status is enabled]
apache_processes           | yes  | no [apache server-status not found. check if mod_status is enabled]
apache_volume              | yes  | no [apache server-status not found. check if mod_status is enabled]
```

PS: server dont have host name (I mean domain), I am using server IP as his hostname now

Can you help me achieve the required setting?

Comment: access the server how you would access the default "domain" you are hosting via _default_ might already do the trick.

Comment: yes, when I move setting from httpd.conf to vhost file for _default_ then I can access /server-status only via 1.2.3.4, but Munin show empty graphs and the error with `apache server-status not found. check if mod_status is enabled`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could get away with creating a vhost with the ServerName you want.
The ServerName in a named-based virtual host setup maps to whatever your browser/HTTP client puts into the `Host` header field.

So this should work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.1.2
    DocumentRoot /var/www/server
    ErrorLog /var/log/www/server_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/www/server_requests.log combined

    <Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from localhost
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The Apache docs (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername) specify you can use an IP as ServerName, and explain how ServerName works as follows:

> If you are using name-based virtual hosts, the ServerName inside a  section specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to match this virtual host.

Comment: +1 With httpd-2.2 remember also to `NameVirtualHost *:80`. Put this as the first VirtualHost *:80 so it would match also older HTTP/1.0 browsers.